# Full featured broker with activeMQ

Tags: spring, websocket

I am using activeMQ as a full featured broker. I have deployed my spring application on Tomcat 8.0.8. I am sending very large messages and I do it in separate Thread (about 230000 stomp messages in while loop). When I use Chrome, or Firefox in activeMQ console, I see that messages are being consumed almost instantly. The problem as always is IE. I can see that it stops to consume messages (after about 1000), and Tomcat fails at

> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) aused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOExcepti n: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffe .java:396) at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426) at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java: 42) at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:31 ) etc....

Is IE such slow a consumer by default or what? I have tried with numerous slow consumer politic with ActiveMQ but without success.

Answer (score 1):

The exception points to an IO error of some sort on the client side. You can try to track what happens on the client side, e.g. use Fiddler to check for any reported errors, or if that fails Wireshark to track what HTTP messages are sent out and how far it gets. Also try using the latest 4.0.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (or better yet 4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT) available from repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot. There are some recent SockJS related fixes worth trying out.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with 4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, but with no success. After a while Fiddler reports:

POST mylink/ami-0.1.0/liveEvents/072/omseen4z/xhr_send?t=1404832405318 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Referer: mylink/ami-0.1.0/liveEvents/iframe.html#ensha4ej
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Host: mylink
Content-Length: 6
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: JSESSIONID=4CC71475E3FF1377C79D77C349710237; theme=standard

["\n"]

and HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found error occurs.

What can be the reason of this(new line message). I have added activemq prefetchSize of 1 and I do ack on every received message.

Marko